# Is it possible to quickly swap workspaces using the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to make it so that when I'm traversing directories using the integrated terminal, running `code .` opens the current working directory in the integrated terminal within the current VSCode window, "discarding"/closing the currently opened workspace, instead of opening a new window for that folder. Is this possible? If not, what would be a similar solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `code -r .`

`code --help` gives the following description:
`-r --reuse-window       Force to open a file or folder in an already opened window.`

Another source is [Visual Studio Code Tips and Tricks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_command-line)

Comment: @user I did edit this one. Is it better to write a new one instead?

Comment: editing is completely fine if you do it soon after initially posting and nobody has commented or voted. Otherwise it can lead to some confusion, but is still technically okay as long as you are the owner of the post. Note on your new answer: It's better though if you include some more info to back up the answer. For example, the doc comment from the `--help` menu, which explains what that option actually does.

Answer (score 0):

As [@ltomase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7211457/ltomase) found in [their answer](/a/75314651) (and exanding on their answer), you can use the `-r` option of the `code` command. The doc comment for this option in the `--help` menu says this:

> Force to open a file or folder in an already opened window.

There are other approaches not involving the command-line:

1. Open command palette and use the `File: Open Workspace from File...` command to open workspace files (`.code-workspace`), or
2. Open command palette and use the `File: Open Folder...` command to open folders (keyboard shortcut: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> , <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>).
3. Use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to open the File menu, then use keyboard navigation to go to "Open Recent" and then select a recent workspace to open.